# How to identify responses from ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sure you've ran into this before so I would like to know how did you deal with this issue.
I have links on my website which on click load ajax content, and sometimes when the user clicks two links and the response from the first click returns after the second request, the application shows the data from the latest response and not from the last link the user have clicked.
What is your best solution for this?
TNX :)

Comment: Abort any pending "old" requests before you make a new one and/or discard all replies except the one to the last request you did send.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to have an order, maintain a variable to keep track of response from both the requests. Store responses from both the requests and then only when , you have shown response of first request, set the variable to show second response